# Github cloning fatal remote error

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I am currently trying to clone from GitHub, and am met with an error:

> git clone git://github.com/StevenHickson/PiAUISuite.git
>   Cloning into 'PiAUISuite'
>   fatal: remote error:
>      repository not found.

How do I go about cloning this?

Comment: I upvoted the question, because when beginner starts with git, and his eyes aren't used to SSH-repository path `ssh://git@github.com:username/repo.git`, it's easy to confuse with `https://github.com/username/repo.git`

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** use the SSH link *(git:// protocol, the git@github.com thingy)* for this particular repository because it isn't allowed, as we can see on the [github page.](https://github.com/StevenHickson/PiAUISuite)

[image: Only HTTPS and Subversion is allowed.]

---

Use the [HTTPS link](https://github.com/StevenHickson/PiAUISuite.git).

```
git clone https://github.com/StevenHickson/PiAUISuite.git
```

Comment: Now, when I do this, it says it is cloning then suddenly stops.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi ~ $ git clone https://github.com/StephenHickson/PiAUISuite.git
Cloning into 'PiAUISuite'...
pi@raspberrypi ~ $

Comment: Ah! I have managed to do it (Not entirely sure how) but thanks anyway.

Comment: That's great! Please upvote if you think this answer is useful. Accept this answer by clicking the check mark on the left if you think this is the solution to your problem. Have a nice day!